# Orthogonal transformations on $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that, if $T$ is an orthogonal transformation on $\mathbb R^2$ such that $\det T = -1$, there exists an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb R^2$ such that the matrix of $T$ with respect to this basis is

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know what an orthogonal transformation is? If yes, can you please include the definition in your question? Thank you.

Comment: What properties do orthogonal matrices have with regards to diagonalization? What must the diagonal entries be? Why can't T be a rotation?

Answer (score 1):

$T$ is an unitary transformation, so it's diagonalizable. And because it's over $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\det(T)=-1$, its eigenvalues are 1 and -1. So it can be diagonlized into $diag(-1,1)$.

Comment: It is not true in general that orthogonal transformations have real eigenvalues.

Answer (score 0):

The transformation is a reflection. There is a vector $e_1$ such that $Te_1=-e_1$ and a vector $e_2$ such that $Te_2 =e_2$.  Choose $e_1, e_2$ as your basis.

Comment: But of course OP has to prove all the assertions in this answer.

Comment: Yes. He has to do the other half of the work.

Comment: If $A$ is an orthogonal transformation and $\lambda$ an eigenvalue of $A$ then $\lambda$ has modulus $1$.   In fact $$(v,v)=(Av, Av)=(\lambda v , \lambda v )=|\lambda|^2 (v,v) \ .$$ Therefore $|\lambda |=1$.